# Any way to get dictionary item from javascript in Sitecore 7.2?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I'm wondering if there is a built in method to get/retrieve dictionary item from Sitecore in JavaScript. We have some text that needs to be translated within our JavaScript widgets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `ItemWebApi` - there are some good examples on how to do that here: https://sitecorecreative.wordpress.com/2013/02/28/sitecore-web-api-client-library/

I would go a different route tho.  If I need to translate text for use in JavaScript I'll either pass in the translated text when I initialize the widget or I would set a data attribute on the DOM element that the widget uses:

```
<div id="widgetContainer" data-text-one="@Model.TranslatedTextOne" data-text-two="@Model.TranslatedTextTwo">
</div>
```

Somthing like that.

Comment: Alright. Passing the translated text via options was my initial thought. That's fair enough :)

Answer (score 0):

I blogged a convenient way on how to get sitecore dictionary in JavaScript:
http://jockstothecore.com/get-sitecore-dictionary-in-js